# What's the meaning of the numbers printed below the message of console.log?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing some testing in chrome debugger tool, I find some strange numbers are printed below the texts output by console.log:
[image]

I didn't log in the console, why are they there? what are these numbers? what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chrome console logs the value of the last expression executed. In the first example above, the last line, `i++;` logs `9`. In the second example, `i+=1;` logs `10`.